# How to grep first match and second match(ignore first match) with awk or sed or grep?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

```
> root# ps -ef | grep [j]ava |  awk '{print $2,$9}'                                                             
> 45134 -Dapex=APEC
> 45135 -Dapex=JAAA
> 45136 -Dapex=APEC
```

I need to put the first APEC of first as First PID, third line of APEC and Second PID and last one as Third PID.

I've tried awk but no expected result.

```
> First_PID =ps -ef | grep [j]ava |  awk '{print $2,$9}'|awk '{if ($0 == "[^0-9]" || $1 == "APEC:") {print $0; exit;}}'
```

Expected result should look like this.

```
> First_PID=45134
> Second_PID=45136
> Third_PID=45135
```

Comment: The output you posted does not look like a complete output from `ps`. Further, you grep for _java_ , but this string does not appear in your output.

Comment: From `the input you specified, wouldn't be a `...| grep -oE '[0-9]+'` more suitable than `... | awk`, provided that you assign the output of this output first to an **array**, and then pick `First_PID` etc. from the array?

Comment: `grep` is almost always superfluous when sending data to `awk`. Your top line is equivalent to `root# ps -ef | awk ' /[j]ava/{print $2,$9}'`. `action` blocks `({})` in awk are conditionally applied to lines containing the regex `pattern` (`//`) that precedes them. I'm afraid I don't understand the "I need to..." part and so can't help further.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```bash
ps -ef | grep [j]ava | 
awk '
{
  val=$2 OFS $9
  match(val,/([0-9]+) -Dapex=APEC ([0-9]+) -Dapex=JAAA\s([0-9]+)/,arr)
  print "First_PID="arr[1],"Second_PID=",arr[3],"Third_PID=",arr[2]
}
'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried to run your recommend but it shown nothing and get 3 times repeat.
First_PID= Second_PID=  Third_PID= 
First_PID= Second_PID=  Third_PID= 
First_PID= Second_PID=  Third_PID=

Comment: @Teerawat, `ps -ef | grep [j]ava` what is the output for this command?

Comment: ps -ef | grep [j]ava will show java application process which contain more than 20 lines for each PID
ps -ef | grep [j]ava |  awk '{print $2,$9}'  will show 3 java processes. I grep just only PID and name of java app. 
45134 -Dapex=APEC
45135 -Dapex=JAAA
45136 -Dapex=APEC

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$ input=("1 APEC" "2 JAAA" "3 APEC")
$ printf '%s\n' "${input[@]}" | grep APEC | sed -n '2p'
3 APEC
```

Explanation:

- `input=(...)` - input data in an array, for testing
- `printf '%s\n' "${input[@]}"` - print `input` array, one element per line
- `grep APEC` - keep lines containing `APEC` only
- `sed -n` - run `sed` without automatic print
- `sed -n '2p'` - print only the second line

Comment: Thanks Lien for your answer and explain. I've just got the new idea from your idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the APECs first...

```
ps -ef |
  awk '/java[ ].* -Dapex=APEC/{print $2" "$9; next; }
       /java[ ]/{non[NR]=$2" "$9}
       END{ for (rec in non) print non[rec] }'
```

If possible, use an array instead of those ordinally named vars.

```
mapfile -t pids < <( ps -ef | awk '/java[ ].* -Dapex=APEC/{print $2; next; }
 /java[ ]/{non[NR]=$2} END{ for (rec in non) print non[rec] }' )
```

Answer (score 0):

After read from everyone idea,I end up with the very simple solution.

```bash
FIRST_PID=$(ps -ef | grep APEC | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'| sed -n '1p') 
SECOND_PID=$(ps -ef | grep APEC | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'| sed -n '2p') 
JAWS_PID=$(ps -ef | grep JAAA | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```